# Error NoClassDeffFoundError Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, intellij-idea

Tengo un proyecto Java que genero builds tanto desde Jenkins como desde mi máquina local con Intellj. Funcionan correctamente desde Intellj y los que genero desde Jenkins los pongo sobre el mismo server Tomcat 9 y funcionan perfectamente.

En cambio, estoy probando desde Eclipse, y el server intenta levantar hasta un punto que lanza esta excepción:

***Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/AbstractCreatorProcessor***

No entiendo qué puede estar pasando, si es el mismo Server que uso en Intell. No entiendo porque no vincula algunas libs externas si están en los poms

Answer (score 0):

Me huele a un bug en openjdk que no sigue el estandard al pie de la letra, mientras que eclipse que tiene su propio runtime si. Creo recordar que java 9 jaws.xml.* com.sun.* se quito del jre. Solución rapida:

https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-comsunxmlstreambufferxmlstreambuffer/